# V2 google api is not returning my old files

Tags: google-drive-api, google-apis-explorer

I am using google drive api V2 for fetch my files and folders.
but it's not returning my old files.

When Year is changed like it was working perfect in 2017 and now it's 2018 it's not returns all file from 2017

Code:

```
const logger = require('../helpers/logger').get('GoogleDriveService');
const googleapis = require('googleapis');
const OAuth2 = googleapis.auth.OAuth2;
const drive = googleapis.drive('v2');
const plus = googleapis.plus('v1');

list(folderId) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

      let folder = (folderId) ? folderId : 'root';
      logger.info('Fetching files from folder %s', folder);
      let settings = { userId: 'me', maxResults: 1000 };
      if(folderId) {
        settings.q = GoogleDriveService.getFolderId(folderId);
      }
      drive.files.list(settings, (err, response) => {
        if(err) {
          logger.error('Failed fetching files from folder %s', folder);
          reject(err);
        }
        else {
          logger.info('Success fetching files from folder %s', folder);
          logger.info('Total File fatch %s', response.items.length);
          logger.info('selfLink %s', response.selfLink);
          logger.info('nextPageToken %s', response.nextPageToken);
          logger.info('nextLink %s', response.nextLink);
          logger.info('incompleteSearch %s', response.incompleteSearch);
          resolve(response.items);
        }
      });
    });
  },
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try using [`v3`](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-sdk) or the ["Try it"](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/list) if it still persist?

Comment: I've used it and it's return all data but it's not return all detail about file 

it's only return **Id, mimeType, Name**

Comment: For v3 you have to request specific fields, as stated in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/migration#notable_changes), "Full resources are no longer returned by default. Use the fields query parameter to request specific fields to be returned."